# Understanding Ruby sort_by

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and I struggle understanding `sort_by!`. This method does something magically I really don't understand.

Here is a simple example:

```
pc= ["Z6","Z5","Z4"]

c = [
    {
        id: "Z4",
        name: "zlah1"
    },
    {
        id: "Z5",
        name: "blah2"
    },
    {
        id: "Z6",
        name:  "clah3"
    }
]


c.sort_by! do |c|
 pc.index c[:id] 
end
```

This procedure returns:

> => [{:id=>"Z6", :name=>"clah3"}, {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"blah2"}, {:id=>"Z4", :name=>"zlah1"}]

It somehow reverses the array order. How does it do that? `pc.index c[:id]` just returns a number. What does this method do under the hood? The documentation is not very beginners friendly.

Comment: _"pc.index c[:id] just returns a number"_ – its return value determines the order. It returns `0` for `"Z6"`, `1` for `"Z5"` and `2` for `"Z4"`. The array is being sorted accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we are given the following:

```
order = ['Z6', 'Z5', 'Z4']
array = [{id: 'Z4', name: 'zlah1'},
         {id: 'Z5', name: 'blah2'},
         {id: 'Z6', name: 'clah3'},
         {id: 'Z5', name: 'dlah4'}]
```

Notice that I added a 4<sup>th</sup> hash (`{id: 'Z5', name: 'dlah4'}`) to the array `array` given in the question. I did this so that two elements of `array` would the same value for the key `:id` (`"Z5"`).

Now let's consider how Ruby might implement the following:

```
array.sort_by { |hash| order.index(hash[:id]) }
  #=> [{:id=>"Z6", :naCme=>"clah3"},
  #    {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"blah2"},
  #    {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"dlah4"},
  #    {:id=>"Z4", :name=>"zlah1"}]
```

That could be done in four steps.

**Step 1: Create a hash that maps the values of the sort criterion to the values of `sort_by`'s receiver**

```
sort_map = array.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |hash,h|
  h[order.index(hash[:id])] << hash
end
  #=> {2=>[{:id=>"Z4", :name=>"zlah1"}],
  #    1=>[{:id=>"Z5", :name=>"blah2"}, {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"dlah4"}],
  #    0=>[{:id=>"Z6", :name=>"clah3"}]}
```

`h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }` creates an empty hash with a *default proc* that operates as follows when evaluating:

```
h[k] << hash
```

If `h` has a key `k` this operation is performed as usual. If, however, `h` does not have a key `k` the proc is called, causing the operation `h[k] = []` to be performed, after which `h[k] << hash` is executed as normal.

The values in this hash must be arrays, rather than individual elements of `array`, due the possibility that, as here, two elements of `sort_by`'s receiver map to the same key. Note that this operation has nothing to do with the particular mapping of the elements of `sort_by`'s receiver to the sort criterion.

**Step 2: Sort the keys of `sort_map`**

```
keys = sort_map.keys
  #=> [2, 1, 0] 
sorted_keys = keys.sort
  #=> [0, 1, 2]
```

**Step 3: Map `sorted_keys` to the values of `sort_map`**

```
sort_map_values = sorted_keys.map { |k| sort_map[k] }
  #=> [[{:id=>"Z6", :name=>"clah3"}],
  #    [{:id=>"Z5", :name=>"blah2"}, {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"dlah4"}],
  #    [{:id=>"Z4", :name=>"zlah1"}]]
```

**Step 4: Flatten `sort_map_values`**

```
sort_map_values.flatten
  #=> [{:id=>"Z6", :name=>"clah3"},
  #    {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"blah2"},
  #    {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"dlah4"},
  #    {:id=>"Z4", :name=>"zlah1"}]
```

One of the advantages of using `sort_by` rather than `sort` (with a block) is that the sort criterion (here `order.index(hash[:id])`) is computed only once for each element of `sort_by`'s receiver, whereas `sort` would recompute these values for each pairwise comparison in its block. The time savings can be considerable if this operation is computationally expensive.

Answer (score 2):

```
order = ['Z6', 'Z5', 'Z4']
array = [{id: 'Z4', name: 'zlah1'},
         {id: 'Z5', name: 'blah2'},
         {id: 'Z6', name: 'clah3'}]

array.sort_by { |hash| order.index(hash[:id]) }
#=> [{:id=>"Z6", :name=>"clah3"}, {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"blah2"}, {:id=>"Z4", :name=>"zlah1"}]
```

This doesn't magically reverse the order of the array. To explain what happens we first need to understand what `order.index(hash[:id])` does. This becomes better visible with the `map` method.

```
array.map { |hash| order.index(hash[:id]) }
#=> [2, 1, 0]
```

Like you can see, the first element with *id* `'Z4'` will return the number `2` since `'Z4'` in the `order` array has index `2`. The same happens with all other array elements. The retuned value is used to sort the objects, `sort_by` will always sort asynchronous, so the order of the above array should become `[0, 1, 2]`. However, the actual content is not replaced, the number is only used for comparison vs other elements. Thus resulting in:

```
#=> [{:id=>"Z6", :name=>"clah3"}, {:id=>"Z5", :name=>"blah2"}, {:id=>"Z4", :name=>"zlah1"}]
```

Comment: `array.map { |hash| [order.index(hash[:id]), hash] }.sort.map(&:last)` is roughly how `sort_by` works.

Comment: @Stefan with the caveat that if `order.index(hash[:id])` were to return the same number twice all of that would fall apart because `Hash` is not "comparable" (e.g. does not implement a spaceship operator `<=>` required by `sort`)

Comment: I guess that's why Stefan used the word *"roughly"*.